# How can I hide the battery meter in Crysis?

Tags: crysis

I recently got Cryis (1) on Steam and there is a little battery meter reading "100%" in the top-right corner of the screen, even during cutscenes.

Apparently the battery meter is there because I'm playing on my laptop. Crysis runs on my laptop just fine, and I don't have a desktop PC that could run the game.

So, is there any way to hide or get rid of that "N/A ||||| 100%", at least during cutscenes? Thank you for your time.

Top-right corner:

[image: Battery meter in top-right]

Answer (score 5):

Today I independently discovered how to disable the battery indicator in Crysis. You will need 7-Zip or WinRAR in order to open the GameData.pak file that is located in the installation folder: `Crysis\Game\GameData.pak`. Once you are inside of the .pak file, navigate to the `libs\UI` folder and find `HUD_Battery.gfx` and `HUD_Battery.swf` and change the filenames (ex. "HUD_BatteryDISABLED.gfx").

You can also change UI text messages by editing the strings contained within the `ui_text_messages.xml` located in the `Crysis\Game\Localized\english.pak` and `Crysis\Game\Localized\English1.pak` files. I did this to remove the "SAVING GAME", "GAME SAVED", and "GAMED SUCCESSFULLY LOADED." text messages from the game.

The keymap tutorial messages that pop up throughout the game can be disabled by changing the text strings under any of the `<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Tutorial.*</Data></Cell>` sections in the `ui_text_messages.xml` file located in `Crysis\Game\Localized\english.pak`. Just search for "Tutorial." and remove the text string below it: i.e. `<Cell ss:StyleID="s23"><Data ss:Type="String">REMOVE_TEXT_LOCATED_HERE</Data></Cell>`